# Creating database but when I want to add an item, it doesnt see a column in database table

Tags: android, database

I created a databse like this And when I try to add a note inte it, I get an error which says table notes has no column named title.

```
private static final String TABLE_NOTES = "notes";
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_DATE_TIME = "time";
private static final String KEY_CHIELD_OF = "chield_of";
private static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
private static final String KEY_NOTE = "note";

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_NOTES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NOTES + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," 
            + KEY_DATE_TIME + " INTEGER,"
            + KEY_CHIELD_OF + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_TITLE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_NOTE + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_NOTES_TABLE);

}

void addNotes(Notes note) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_CHIELD_OF, note.getChieldOf()); 
    values.put(KEY_TITLE,     note.getTitle()); 
    values.put(KEY_NOTE,      note.getNote()); 

    db.insert(TABLE_NOTES, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}
```

where is my mistake ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have your application installed on a device or emulator and you added a new column to a table, `onCreate` method is not called (it is only called once when the database is installed).

Please uninstall your app and install it again.

Comment: I think that was my problem. Iwas about to get crazy. Thank you very much.

Comment: @AliTuran - Increasing the database version number will also cause onCreate to be called again. This would be the preferred way since when actual users have your app installed you can't expect them to uninstall and reinstall whenever you make a DB change.

Comment: @dymmeh it will call `onUpgrade` in this case

Comment: Oops. Pretend I said nothing *fades away in the background*

Comment: Ah i tought that u wrote again, didnt check who wrote lol :) then thnx to @Szymon